# Node JS Webscraping with Cheerio Problem to fetch the html on some websites

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

im trying to learn webscraping and the code i wrote works for some URLs, but some just dont fetch any HTML. When i run the script there are 0 logs or errors shown in the terminal and the terminal switches into the next command line.

Here is my code which works for some websites, but for this for example not:

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

request("https://reverb.com/", function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(html);
  }
});
```

The teriminal looks liket this, so basically i dont fetch or scrape any html...any idea why?

```
PS C:\Users\XY\Documents\Javascript\grabbercheerio> node app.js
PS C:\Users\XY\Documents\Javascript\grabbercheerio>
```

Comment: Try debugging by removing the if-statement and do `console.log(error)` and `console.log(response` to see what error you get.

Comment: Hello, its giving me back null. So why its giving me null?
Thank you for your quick reply. Im a very beginner thanks for showing me this! i wil have a deeper look into debugging after fixing this :) Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code with minor changes and it works fine. I've uploaded an answer with an explaination.

Answer (score 0):

If your error has a value, something went wrong. Then what you want to do is to log the error and exit the function. If the error has no value or `null`, everything went fine and you can use the data.

This example is a more efficient approach.

```
const request = require('request');

request('https://reverb.com/', function(error, _response, data) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log('Something went wrong!', error);         
    }

    // Everything went fine
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful!